# Surface 2.0 SurfaceTextBox get text

Tags: keyboard, user-input, pixelsense

I having a SurfaceTextBox with text from a database. The user can manipulate the text with the SurfaceKeyboard. But how do I get the new text the user entered?

I looked and didn't find any example.

Answer (score 1):

just look at the .Text property of it

Comment: Thanks, my bad. I tried with the wrong TextBox in my example.